# deploying mancenter for hazelcast with LDAP config - Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ldap, hazelcast, configmap

I am trying to deploy mancenter for hazelcast 5.1.4 using kubernetes, But I need to setup the ldap from starting up.

in the version 3.12.x, I use to set a configmap with a value ldap.properties and once the pod was up I could use the ldap login, but from version 4..x.x onwards looks like this change.

Anyone has tried to set this in version 4.x.x or 5.x.x?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From this latest release 5.0, Yo can find the setup in this [official doc](https://docs.hazelcast.com/management-center/5.3-snapshot/deploy-manage/ldap).

You can use your existing LDAP server for authentication/authorization on the Management Center.To create and manage additional users, you must configure them on the LDAP server.

You can use the  `ldap update-password` task in the hz-mc conf tool to update the encrypted LDAP password stored in the keystore.
This command expects information about the keystore such as its location and password and the new LDAP password that you want to use. After updating the LDAP password, you need to click on the Reload Security Config button on the Management Center login page.